# SQLITE: import data from a CSV

Tags: csv, import, sqlite, spatialite

I need to import in a SQLITE database a CSV file that use both numbers than strings: here you a sample ..

```
col_1|col_2|col_3
10|text2|http://www.google.com
```

For the import I use Spatialite GUI because I've to manage also spatial data: all works fine in the import but when I try to select the data

```
select * from test;
```

[image]

How I've to structure my CSV file to store my "text2" string?

Comment: What SpatiaLite GUI version are you using?

Comment: In my "spatialite_gui 2.0.0-devel" there's "Import CSV/TXT".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved in a different manner ....

Enter in Sqlite and give these commands:

```
CREATE TABLE ps_details(
  col_1 TEXT,
  col_2 TEXT,
  col_3 TEXT
);
.mode csv
.separator |
.import test.csv test
.quit
```

You can save this in a file (es. `test.txt`) and then, in a second file named `test.sh` write

```
sqlite3 dbtest.sqlite < test.txt
```

save and change its permission (`chmod 777`), and then launch it form comand line

```
./test.sh
```

This will create a table `test` in your `dbtest.sqlite` getting data form `test.csv` file

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you defined the type of `col_2` as `REAL`, where it should be `TEXT`.

The structure of your CSV look ok.

*Disclaimer: I have never used Spatialite, this is just from looking at the information you provided.*

Comment: In the import I don't define the types of my columns ... It seems that it fix the type to REAL or something and not text as I suppose

Comment: SQLite ignores column types, they are there just for compatibility. You can skip them as well.